# view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

I am a beginner in django I'm getting this error when running :

```
python manage.py runserver
```

this is my app url (main.urls)

```
from . import views
from main import views as main_views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from main.views import blog, about
from django.conf.urls import include, url

urlpatterns = [
    path('about/', 'main.views.about', name='about'),
    path('', 'main.views.blog', name='blog'),
]
```

this is my full project:
https://github.com/ouakkaha/pr
i will be so thankful if you find i solution for me:)

Comment: Show us the definitions of `main.views.about` and `main.views.blog`.

Comment: do you mean the urls of the root

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().

Comment: I would guess that the second argument to `path` should *not* be quoted, and since you import `from main.views import blog, about`, you should probably use only the names `blog` and `about` :)

Comment: i change it like this:from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('about/', main.views.about, name='about'),
    path('', main.views.blog, name='blog'),
]but they show me this NameError: name 'main' is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should instantiate your `path`s by removing the quotes of your views referencing:

```
from main.views import blog, about


urlpatterns = [
    path('about/', about, name='about'),
    path('', blog, name='blog'),
]
```

Since you've already imported your views, you should only write their names.

---

*More info in [the docs.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#example)*

Comment: I try it but they show me this error NameError: name 'main' is not defined

Comment: @khadijaouakkaha I've just fixed it with the proper solution.

Comment: I did it but it still showing me the same error  TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().

Answer (score 0):

I believe wencakisa's answer should solve the problem, but let me explain everything from the very beginning, maybe it'll make things clearer.

In the `path` function, you need to pass three arguments:

1. the route - this will be part of the URL address. It has to be a string;
2. the view - as the error message says, it has to be a **callable** - something that can be called, for example a **function**;
3. the name (optional) - it's less important here; it has to be a string.

In your code, you put the **second** arguments to `path` in quotes, which means that they are just strings, and not functions:

```
'main.views.about'  # this is a string - just a few characters put together
main.views.about   # this is a function, defined in the directory `main`, 
                   # in the file `views`
```

Another problem is the imports. There's a few unnecessary import statements in your file. If you want to use objects (functions, classes etc.) from file A in file B, you have to import them in the file B. You can do it in a few ways:

```
from . import views  # reads: "from the same directory in which the current file (B) is, 
                    # import `views.py`, and everything that's inside it." 
                    # This is called "a relative import"
# and then you can use the imported objects like this:
path('about/', views.about, name='about')
```

```
from main import views as main_views  # reads: "from the directory `main` in the project
                                     # import the entire `views`, but call it `main_views`
# and then you can use the imported objects like this:
path('about/', main_views.about, name='about')
```

```
from main.views import blog, about  # reads: from the `main/views.py` import only `blog`
                                    # and `about` - these two are the functions you need
# and then you use them like this:
path('about/', about, name='about')
```

I'd suggest you choose one import style and use it consistently. The last one is quite good in this case, because you can easily see which functions have been imported from the `views` file. The other two import statements are then redundant, you can remove them.

Hopefully this will help you solve your issue.